# How can I find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix without computation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A is
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
I already know that sum of eigenvalues is tr(A)=0 and times of eigenvlaues is det(A)=0. but how to determine eigenvalues??? and how can I get eigenvectors?

Comment: It is clear that the eigenvalue is $0$ since it is an uppertriagular matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This is an upper triangular matrix. In general, the eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are found on the diagonal. This is because $\lambda I-A$ is triangular as well, and the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal entries: $(\lambda-a_{11})(\lambda-a_{22})\cdots(\lambda-a_{nn})$.

Your matrix is known as a [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix), and it is well known (and trivial to verify) that its only eigenvector is $(1,0,0,0)^T$ and multiples thereof.

Answer (score 1):

For an upper triangular matrix the eigenvalues lie on the diagonal. So, they are all zero.

After that, computing four eigenvectors is easy.  If you're working with vectors on the right, $[a,b,c,d]^\top$ is an eigenvector if and only if $b=c=d=0$,  so anything with $a\neq 0$ works.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an upper triangular matrix, so diagonal elements are eigenvalues. For eigenvalues vector at 0 , it can be easily seen that 2nd,3rd and 4th component is zero. So $X = (1,0,0,0)'$